# Speed up array interval comparison using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large set of data points taken in a certain time interval, and I am attempting to compute a weighted average of this data on a different time interval by looking at the overlaps between those two intervals. I have a successful method, described below, but it is rather slow. I'm looking for any suggestions as to how I could make this run faster.

I have two sets of time intervals as well as the data points associated with one of those time intervals. I need to determine which of the data points from the first time intervals fall into the second time intervals. For example, if the following were my arrays:

```
start1 = np.array([1.,6.,11.,16.,21.,26.,31.,36.])
stop1 = np.array([6.,11.,16.,21.,26,31.,36.,41.])
start2 = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.,11.,12.,13.,14.,15.,16.,17.,...,39.])
stop2 = np.array([2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.,11.,12.,13.,14.,15.,16.,17.,18.,...,40.])
data1 = np.array([2.,4.,3.,8.,4.,7.,2.,6.])
```

Then my results would be:

```
[array([ 2.]), array([ 2.]), array([ 2.]), array([ 2.]), array([ 2.,  4.]), array([ 2.,  4.]), array([ 4.]), array([ 4.]), array([ 4.]), array([ 4.,  3.]), array([ 4.,  3.]), array([ 3.]), array([ 3.]), array([ 3.]), array([ 3.,  8.]), array([ 3.,  8.]), array([ 8.]), array([ 8.]), array([ 8.]), array([ 8.,  4.]), array([ 8.,  4.]), array([ 4.]), array([ 4.]), array([ 4.]), array([ 4.,  7.]), array([ 4.,  7.]), array([ 7.]), array([ 7.]), array([ 7.]), array([ 7.,  2.]), array([ 7.,  2.]), array([ 2.]), array([ 2.]), array([ 2.]), array([ 2.,  6.]), array([ 2.,  6.]), array([ 6.]), array([ 6.]), array([ 6.])]
```

This is the method that I am currently using:

```
intervals_data = []
for i in range(0, len(start2)):
    intervals_data.append(data1[((stop1>=start2[i]) & (start1<=stop2[i]))])
```

The problem that I am having is that these arrays are typically on the order of 25,000 elements, so this takes around 20 seconds per data set. I typically have a few hundred data sets, so it end up taking about an hour to run.

Can anyone please point me towards a faster method? Thanks!

Comment: Is it a coincidence that the intervals each of the interval sets are always the same length?

Comment: No, they're typically continuous intervals of the same length. There are cases where this isn't true, but it commonly is.

Comment: What happens if one of the intervals in the second set spans two intervals of the first one? Is it possible? Or just the value of the first interval is taken? Also, can we assume that interval are sorted and each one follows the previous one, so there are no overlapping intervals in the same set?

Comment: @javidcf, it does happen, and both would be taken. Any overlap is accounted for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use binary search to find the left most index `i` for each entry `start2[j]` in `stop1` such that an insertion would keep `stop1` sorted, i.e., `start2[j] <= stop1[i]`. Similarly, we are looking for the right most `i` for each `stop2[j]` in `start1`, i.e., `stop2[j] >= stop1[i]`. This can be achieved as follows:

```python
start_indx = stop1.searchsorted(start2, "left")
end_indx = start1.searchsorted(stop2, "right")
result = [data1[start_indx[i]:end_indx[i]]for i in range(len(start_indx))]
```

Comment: That appears to work for non-inclusive intervals (data1[((stop1>start2[i]) & (start1<stop2[i]))]). Do you know if there's a way to allow it to include an overlap on the boundaries? (i.e. >= and <= rather than > and <)

Comment: I messed things up a little, searching from left is equal to <= and searching from right is >= I'll try to edit my answer to give you a correct solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should give you the right answer and hopefully is much faster, too.

Comment: That's significantly faster! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try an iterator-based approach:

```
inter1 = zip(start1, stop1, data1)
inter2 = zip(start2, stop2)
data2 = []

curr1 = next(inter1)

for curr2 in inter2:
  vals = []
  while curr2[0] > curr1[1]:
    curr1 = next(inter1)
  vals.append(curr1[2])
  while curr2[1] > curr1[1]:
    curr1 = next(inter1)
    vals.append(curr1[2])
  data2.append(np.array(vals))

return data2
```

The point here is that you should only go *forward* along the intervals, so an iterator should do the work.

PD: I'm assuming Python 3.x here. If you are using Python 2.x, just replace `zip` with `izip`.